# Autoload class Kohana

Tags: php, kohana

I read code Kohana and I see

**bootstrap.php**

```
spl_autoload_register(array('Kohana', 'auto_load'));
```

In **index.php**

```
echo SPMY_OMG::$run;
```

I created file in \kohana\application\classes\SPMY\OMG

```
class SPMY_OMG{
static public $run=189;
}
```

Why **ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'SPMY_OMG' not found** ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bootstrap is only run after the index. So the autoloader still has to be defined.

What is it that you want to achieve? If you want to use the autoloader, you have to do that after the autoloader has been setup.

Comment: Thanks.Which file do I get access?

Comment: @MichelPhelps What do you mean?